# How to initialise and access a const char* const*

Tags: c++, pointers, function-prototypes

I saw a C++ code where a struct is defined as below with weird `const char* const*`

```
struct TestStruct {
    const char* const* text; 
    void* data;
};
```

I need to use the above struct and return an object of it from a function. But for that how to initialise the `text` variable to a constant string? Also, how to access the string pointed by `text` from the caller function.

```
TestStruct TestFunction() {
    TestStruct struct_obj;
    // TODO: how to assign struct_obj.text 
}

int main() {
    TestStruct struct_obj = TestFunction();
    // TODO: how to access struct_obj.text
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are immutable, so they cannot be assigned to. They can only be initialized. To return such a struct from a function you can use aggregate initialization (curly brace initialization). This struct can be initialized with any char**, but the one accessing it can only read from the char**, but cannot modify it.

```
TestStruct TestFunction() 
{
    char** lines = new char*[2];
    // Work with char** stored in lines
    *(lines + 0) = new char[10];
    *(lines + 1) = new char[20];
    void* data = nullptr;
    return TestStruct{ lines , data };
}

int main()
{
   TestStruct my_struct = TestFunction();
   // const char* const * means it's an immutable array of immutable CStrings
   const char* line_one = *my_struct.text;
   const char* line_two = *(my_struct.text + 1);
  
   std::cout << line_one << std::endl;
   std::cout << line_two << std::endl;
}
```

Edit:
I decided to clarify a bit further.

"const char* const *" means A pointer-reference to an immutable table of strings.
This means that the reference itself can be changed to refer to some other table at any time.
The maximum level of constness is "const char * const * const" which reads as A pointer-constant-reference to an immutable table. A pointer-constant-reference means it can not point to any other table once constructed and if this was a member of a struct it definitely needs to be aggregate initialized or at least default constructed

Comment: But how to free the memory allocated by `new char[x]` statements?

Comment: You can const_cast<char**> and do the delete[] for each row. But you shouldn't manage this memory through a struct like that. The consts are there to express that the caller is the owner of the memory, so the caller should manage it's lifetime. Usually you have a """Manager""" code that holds a char**  somewhere and it constructs and dispatches such structs to other code for read-only purposes

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to a constant variable, but you can *initialize* such a variable:

```
TestStruct TestFunction() {
    static const char* string = "hello world";

    TestStruct struct_obj = {
        &string,  // The text member
        nullptr   // The data member
    }
    return struct_obj;
}
```

Comment: This gives the error `a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char *const *"`

Comment: Oh, great, and how to access/print the string from main function?

Comment: `std::cout << **struct_obj.text << std::endl;` only prints the first char.

Comment: @Kaustav That's because you dereference the pointer twice. Once for the string, a second time for the first element of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
TestStruct struct_obj;
...
(char*&)struct_obj.text = "works";
```